# How do you find oxidation state of the metals of a complex with two coordination spheres?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds

For example suppose we have $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4][PtCl4]}.$ For the naming of this complex I need to know the oxidation number of the metals; let the oxidation number of first and second $\ce{Pt}$  be $x, y$ respectively, then one can obtain the equation $x+y=4$. How are we supposed to proceed further? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Platinum can exist under two common  oxidation numbers : $+2$ and $+4$. The most reasonable oxidation numbers are $x = y = 2$, because if the first $\ce{Pt}$ atoms is at $+4$, the other one is at zero, which is not reasonable. And if the first $\ce{Pt}$ atom is at zero, $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4]}$ would not be charged, which is contrary to the original formula.

Comment: Do you have a list of common oxidation numbers for transition metals? How do you remember them; do you have some general trends which can ease the memorization process?

Comment: Reference : https://www.rsc.org/periodic-table/element/78/platinum

Comment: @osmium  There are 3 major ways how to reach chemical knowledge 1/Memorize data what is memory challenging. 2/Recognize or learn behaviour patterns, what is challenge in understanding 3/ Derive behaviour from principles of quantum chemistry, what is computational demanding and extremely challenging mathematically and conceptually. Reasonable approach is combination of 1/ and 2/.

Comment: @Osmium Chemistry is too wide and deep domain for a single author or book being the best in all of it. It cannot be at the same time wide enough and deep enough and correct enough. // See also  [Chemistry SE: resources-for-learning-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry)